# Return text from xpath using java?

Tags: string, xpath

I want to get the text using xpath for 2 elements and then concatenate them .

```
  <td><span class="placeholder">hello</span>
      <span class="placeholder2">bye</span> 
  </td>
```

So I want to obtain "hello bye" as a string.

This is what I tried to for obtaining the xpaths of the elements:

```
By byXpath =(By.xpath("//td[@class='placeholder'/text()][1]");
By byXpat =By.xpath("//td[@class='placeholder2'/text()][1]");
```

the "1" value is due to the fact that I have the same td elements repeating for a couple of times and I just want the first one. Thanks

Comment: Try this way.. `String Hello = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='placeholder']")).getText();
     System.out.println(Hello);`

Comment: This doesn't work :( I can't use getText() method.

Comment: Could you try `'//td[span[@class="placeholder"] and span[@class="placeholder2"]]/text()'`?

Comment: So, in which way you want to do this? and why you don't want to use getText()?

Answer (score 0):

```
string(//td)
```

out:

```
'\n      hello\n      bye \n  '
```

OR:

```
normalize-space(//td)
```

out:

```
'hello bye'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use concat function to get what you want. The xpath is :

`concat( (//td/span[@class="placeholder"])[1], " ", (//td/span[@class="placeholder2"])[1] )`

assuming you have the below xml :

```
<root>
 <td><span class="placeholder">hello</span>
      <span class="placeholder2">bye</span> 
  </td>
 <td><span class="placeholder">hello2</span>
      <span class="placeholder2">bye2</span> 
  </td>
</root>
```

The xpath selects the first `td/span` elements and concats

`hello` , space and `bye`  resulting in `hello bye`

Comment: I am very curious to know who downvoted this and why ? I may learn a lot. Thanks.